# Kafka Topics not receiving messages and not being deleted

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I'm having some troubles with kafka topics.
We have on our development environment kafka version 2.0,
and I've checked for topic deletion to be enabled.
Infact I've been able to delete some topics, but there are few that won't be deleted no matter what I do. Brokers are running fine by the way.

Not only that, but it seems that those topics don't receive any message from producers, even though those are correctly configured. We tried change the topic where to send messages and it was fine.

I didn't find anything regard these 2 problems, any of you know anything?

Comment: If a producer is up and running, the topic will still be there (might be truncated though) even if you delete it. Regarding the issue with messages not delivered to topics, you need to share some code along with topic's configuration.

Comment: "no matter what you do" - does that include manually removing the zookeeper entry?